# JLayeredPane not displaying properly

Tags: java, swing, jlayeredpane

I am programming a gui for a chess game, i am using a JLayeredpane in order to display the black and white tiles on the JFrame and then on the next layer of the JLayeredpane I would display the chess pieces, i am new to Jlayeredpane and don't understand quite how to use it, I can't get the pieces layer to overlay on the tiles layer, I tried to set the opacity as false and I tried to set the background color as 0,0,0,0 any ideas?

I created a jpanel that holds an array of jpanels with black and white backgrounds, then I created another jpanel that holds an array of jlabels, the jlabels have texts that display the chess pieces.

Total Code:

```
class frame extends JFrame implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{

private JLabel[][]label;

private int xIndex;

private int yIndex;

private JPanel[][]panels;

private JPanel mainPanel;

private JPanel labelPanel;

    public frame() {    
        super("Chessboard");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        label = new JLabel[8][8];
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        panels = new JPanel[8][8];
        labelPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,8));
        addTiles();
        labelPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,8));
        addButtons();
        JLayeredPane mainPane = new JLayeredPane();
        add(mainPane);
        mainPane.add(mainPanel,1);
        mainPane.add(labelPanel, 2);
        setBoard();
        setSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void setBoard(){

         label[0][0].setText("\u2656");
         label[0][7].setText("\u2656");
         label[0][1].setText("\u2658");
         label[0][2].setText("\u2657");
         label[0][3].setText("\u2655");
         label[0][4].setText("\u2654");
         label[0][5].setText("\u2657");
         label[0][6].setText("\u2658");
         label[7][0].setText("\u265C");
         label[7][1].setText("\u265E");
         label[7][2].setText("\u265D");
         label[7][3].setText("\u265B");
         label[7][4].setText("\u265A");
         label[7][5].setText("\u265D");
         label[7][6].setText("\u265E");
         label[7][7].setText("\u265C");

         for(int i =0; i <8 ;i++){
             label[1][i].setText("\u2659");

         }

         for(int i =0; i <8 ;i++){
             label[6][i].setText("\u265F");

         }

    }

    public void addTiles(){

            for(int i =0; i<8;i++){


            for(int k =0; k<8;k++){

            panels[i][k] = new JPanel();

                if(i%2 == 1){

                    if(k%2 == 0){

        panels[i][k].setBackground(Color.gray);

        }else{

        panels[i][k].setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        }

        }else{

                    if(k%2 == 1){

                    panels[i][k].setBackground(Color.gray);

                    }else{

                    panels[i][k].setBackground(Color.WHITE);

                    }

                }

                mainPanel.add(panels[i][k]);

            }

            }

    }

    public void addButtons(){

        for(int i =0; i<8;i++){
            for(int k =0; k<8;k++){

                label[i][k] = new JLabel();

                label[i][k].setLayout(null);

    label[i][k].setFont(label[i][k].getFont().deriveFont(29f));

                label[i][k].addMouseListener(this);

                label[i][k].addMouseMotionListener(this);

                labelPanel.add(label[i][k]);

            }


        }
    }

    public void findIndex(MouseEvent arg0){

        for(int x =0; x<8;x++){

            for(int y =0; y <8; y++){

                if(arg0.getSource().equals(label[x][y])){

                    xIndex = x;

                    yIndex = y;


                }   
            }   
        }   
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {

        findIndex(arg0);

        int mouseX = arg0.getX();

        int mouseY = arg0.getY();

        label[xIndex][yIndex].setLocation(mouseX, mouseY);
    }
```

I want it so that the pieces layer will display on top of the tiles layer of black and white jpanels and so that the colours are visible.

Comment: Don't use a JLayeredPane. Rather use a simple grid of JPanel to hold the chessboard, make the pieces JLabels, and if you want to lift the pieces off of the board, then place them into the JFrame's glasspane. It is in fact using a JLayeredPane behind the scenes, but is easier to do.

Comment: do i create another panel for the glasspane? sorry, i am not familiar with glasspanes.

Comment: No you do not. Please look it up as it is well explained in easy to find tutorials and such